# Как получить весь список из таблицы с определенным параметром?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в БД, в нем есть 2 параметра, `username` и `user_uuid`.

Как мне получить все столбцы, у которых `user_uuid` равняется `123` и получить вместе с ней параметр `username` в виде массива?

Использую вот такой SQL код:

```sql
SELECT 'username' FROM 'users'
```

Но нужно сделать условие - если `user_uuid` будет `123`, то код должен вернуть мне `user_uuid` и `username` в виде массива, если в таблице не будет параметра `user_uuid` со значением `123`, то должно вернуть пустой массив.

---

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$var = mysql_query(SELECT 'username','user_uuid' FROM 'users' WHERE user_uuid='123');
$var_array = mysql_fetch_array($var);
print_r($var_array);`

```
SELECT 'username','user_uuid' FROM 'users' WHERE user_uuid='123'
```

Все данные из базы выходят в виде массива.
Если user_uuid='123' будет пуст то и массив будет пуст.

```
$res = $mysql->query(SELECT 'username','user_uuid' FROM 'users' WHERE user_uuid='123');
$row = $res->fetch_array();
print_r($row);
```

Под PDO сами разберетесь. Разницы не много.

Comment: Используйте три апострофа для подвсетки кода **```**

Comment: [`mysql`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) - данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов Данный код был в качестве примера. Ибо процедурку все знают. В принципе MySqli Тоже самое только ты вытягиваешь query из конекта.